# Question form of I wish

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, questions, wish

1. I like basketball.
2. What do you like?

2 is the question form of 1.

3.I wish English was easy?

Then, what is the question form of 3?

I don't want to get what people wish something was easy as an answer, I want to know what they wish English was like.

Comment: *What do you wish was easy?* Alternatively (in a somewhat contrived context) *What do you wish English was?*

Comment: I am trying to find question that asks people what they wish a particular thing was.

Comment: I don't want to get what people wish something was easy as an answer,  I want to know what they wish English was like.

Comment: In that case you *are* looking at my second ("contrived") suggestion. The "particular thing" being *English*, where what you wish is that it could be *easy* as opposed to, say, "incomprehensible").

Comment: Thank you so much. But is there any way to ask in terms of difficultt?

Comment: I don't really see what you're getting at. Perhaps *You don't like the fact that English is **difficult**, so what do you **want** it to be?* But what's the point of asking such a convoluted question?

Comment: MAYBE I CAN SAY "What do you wish English was in terms of difficulty" am i right?

Comment: *Syntactically*, you could validly ask such a question. But who in their right mind would do so, given that you'd have to be insane to want languages to be anything other than ***easy*** to learn? (Which of course they're not, but *You can't always get what you want!* :)

Answer (score 1):

The question would be:

> *What do you wish was easy?*

And then you could respond with:

> I wish English was easy